# I have problem when saving codes in VSCode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, django

I just migrated to Ubuntu. I have a problem when saving codes in VSCode. It keeps asking me to enter the password. It seems that this problem occurs when working with Docker.

[image]

Comment: you can follow the steps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20984/always-sudo-privileges

Comment: Is VSCode installed as a snap?

Comment: I installed VSCode using this command (sudo snap install code --classic)